# creating a filter function in R

Tags: r, filtering

I am trying to create a filter function that would select the same genes that I select with this code, but I am completely lost and don't know how to approach it

```
allB <- ALL[,which(ALL$BT %in% c("B1","B2", "B3","B4"))]
levels(allB$BT)[levels(allB$BT)=="B3"] <- "B34"
levels(allB$BT)[levels(allB$BT)=="B4"] <- "B34"

design.ma <- model.matrix(~ 0 + factor(allB$BT))
colnames(design.ma) <- c("B1","B2","B34")
fit <- lmFit(allB, design.ma) 
fit <- eBayes(fit) 
cont.ma <- makeContrasts(B1-B2,B2-B34, levels=factor(allB$BT)) 
cont.ma
fit1 <- contrasts.fit(fit, cont.ma)
fit1 <- eBayes(fit1)

dim( topTable(fit, number=Inf, p.value=0.05,adjust.method="fdr"))
min(exprs(allB)) 
dim( topTable(fit1, number=Inf, p.value=0.05, adjust.method="fdr"))
```

This selects a total of 1169 genes from the expression set.

Comment: not sure what do you mean, a function that can take a generic data set and run the same code? `f <- function(data) {## code here}` where you replace the instances of `ALL` with `data`, then `f(ALL)` will "select the same genes that [you] select with this code"

Comment: is it really that easy? Thanks, I didn't think it would be so simple